# Doctrine 2 - Association table with additional properties & inheritance

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, associations

I'm just starting with Doctrine (no experience with ORMs so far) on my first Symfony2 project.

I have a pretty simple structure, but am not satisfied with how classes are generated.
I looked for tutorials/related questions on stackoverflow, but I haven't found a comprehensive answer so far :

Let say I have 2 entities + an association table with additional properties :

```
User
- id: int
- name: string
- movies: UserMovie

Movie
- id: int
- name: string
- duration: int

UserMovie:
- user_id: int
- movie_id: int
- seen: bool
```

A user can have several movies / a movie can be owned by several users.

What I would like is to have the generated UserMovie class inheriting from Movie, so I can access movies properties from a UserMovie instance directly.

I'd like to get something like this as a result of the generation process:

```
class UserMovie extends Movie
{
  protected $user;      // User instance
  protected $id;        // inherited from Movie
  protected $name;      // inherited from Movie
  protected $duration;  // inherited from Movie
}
```

Is this even possible?
Is there some best practices in this case?

Not sure this is clear enough (as I said earlier, I'm pretty new to this), any help would be gladly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear enough :)

You should build

`User hasMany UserMovies`

`Movie hasMany UserMovies`

relations. That will allow you to do something like this

```
var_dump( $user->hasMovie($movie) ) ;
```

by doing

```
class User
{
    public function hasMovie(Movie $movie)
    {
        foreach($this->usermovies as $m2m) {
            if ( $m2m->getMovie() === $movie ) 
                return true ;
        }
        return false ;
    }

    public function addMovie(Movie $movie)
    {
        if ( !$this->hasMovie($movie) ) {
            $m2m = new UserMovie() ;
            $m2m->setMovie($movie) ;
            $m2m->setUser($this) ;
            $this->usermovies->add($m2m) ;
        }
    }
}
```

or alike